# Strip initial question mark from ajax request in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So I am trying to send an Ajax request to a server but I need to strip the initial question mark from the request

the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  (function($){
      function processForm( e ){
        var callid = $('.callid').val();
        var pin = $('.pin').val();
        var urlFinal = callid+'/'+pin;
          $.ajax({
              url: 'https://httpbin.org/get/',
              dataType: 'text',
              type: 'get',
              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              //$(this).serialize()
              data: urlFinal,
              success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                console.log('success' + data.streamFileUrl)
                $('.overlay').show();
                $('#video').html( data.streamFileUrl );
              },
              error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                  console.log('OH NOES');
                  $('.incorrect').show()
              }
          });

          e.preventDefault();
      }

      $('#form').submit( processForm );

  })(jQuery);

})
```

The Result:

```
https://httpbin.org/get/?1234/1234
```

What I'm after:

```
https://httpbin.org/get/1234/1234
```

Comment: Append `urlFinal` to the string you provide to `url` instead of adding it to the `data` argument.

Comment: Thanks that works :) if you write it as an answer I can select you for points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're sending a GET request jQuery will automatically add data to the querystring for you.

To avoid this, append `urlFinal` to the string you provide to `url` instead of adding it to the `data` argument.

```
var urlFinal = callid + '/' + pin;
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://httpbin.org/get/' + urlFinal,
  dataType: 'text',
  type: 'get',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
   // ...
  },
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can just append the urlFinal to baseUrl like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  (function($){
      function processForm( e ){
        var callid = $('.callid').val();
        var pin = $('.pin').val();
        var urlFinal = callid+'/'+pin;
          $.ajax({
              url: 'https://httpbin.org/get/' + urlFinal,
              dataType: 'text',
              type: 'get',
              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                console.log('success' + data.streamFileUrl)
                $('.overlay').show();
                $('#video').html( data.streamFileUrl );
              },
              error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                  console.log('OH NOES');
                  $('.incorrect').show()
              }
          });

          e.preventDefault();
      }

      $('#form').submit( processForm );

  })(jQuery);

})
```